# Delayed response CursorLoader on a fragment

Tags: android

My fragment according to the logcat seems to be have updated the CursorLoader, but does not actually display until I swipe left and right(to other fragments) and than it finally displays. How can i have it immediately displaying the info?

```
public class ThreeFragments extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>  {//

public static final int RECENT_ARREST_FRAG = 1;
public static final int SEARCH_BY_NAME_FRAG = 2;
public static final int FAVORITE_FRAG = 3;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public static final String ARG_FRAG_TYPE = "frag_arg_type";
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
private int thisFragType = 0;
private Activity mActivity;
static boolean recent = false;
static boolean search = false;
static boolean favorite = false;
public static int thisFragTypew = 0;
FavoriteAdapter adapter;
List<TodoItem> items;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_prod_list, container, false);
    mActivity = getActivity();
    thisFragType = getArguments().getInt(ARG_FRAG_TYPE, 0);
    thisFragTypew = getArguments().getInt(ARG_FRAG_TYPE, 1);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);

    adapter = new FavoriteAdapter(new FavoriteAdapter.ItemClickListenerPublic() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClickedPublic(TodoItem itemPublic) {

        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "The Frag Type is: " + thisFragType);
    setupRecyclerView(rv);
    return rv;
}

private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    switch (thisFragType) {
        case (RECENT_ARREST_FRAG):
            recent = true;
            search = false;
            favorite = false;
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), getDataListNamesOfStates()));
            break;
        case (SEARCH_BY_NAME_FRAG):
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext(), 2));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapterSearchByName(getActivity(), getDataListNamesOfStates()));
            recent = false;
            search = true;
            favorite = false;
            break;
        case (FAVORITE_FRAG):

            Log.d(TAG,"FAVORITE_FRAG was called");
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext(), 2));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), getDataListNamesOfFavorites()));

            break;
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Loader Created");
    return new CursorLoader(ThreeFragments.this.getActivity(), TodoItemsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Load Finished");
    if(data != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "We have " + data.getCount() + " items");
        if(data.getCount() == 0){

            return;
        }
        data.moveToFirst();
        items= new LinkedList<>();
        do{
            items.add(TodoItem.buildFromCursor(data));

        }while (data.moveToNext());
        Log.d(TAG,"items:"+items.get(0).getText()+"  " + items.get(0).getTextSubtitle());
    }else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Data returned null!");
    }
}
  @Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Loader reset");
}
```

Comment: your data model is a `Cursor`, so why dont you use a `[Simple]CursorAdapter`?

Comment: scroll down you will see it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jDjbxG58

Comment: @pskink can you please explain more what exactly you mean (or a link), better yet if you have a way to do it with RecyclerView I will appreciate.

Comment: read [this](http://quanturium.github.io/2015/04/19/using-cursors-with-the-new-recyclerview/) or similar links